# More convenient way to localize in windows phone apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Currently, if you want to localize say Application Title in a windows phone app you would do this:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, 
                  Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

This is too long, and certain parts are repeated for each binding. Even if you were to rename `LocalizedResources` property to `R` and `LocalizedStrings` class to `LS` for example, some repetition still exist.

So I tried making a class that inherits from `Binding` class and implemented as follows:

```cs
public class LocalizedBinding : Binding {
    public LocalizedBinding(string path) : base(path) {
        Source = Application.Current.Resources["LocalizedStrings"];
    }
}
```

The hope was to use it as follows:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{b:LocalizedBinding LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle}" />
```

However, the app crashes immediately upon start and I can't see any errors even in debugger. Any tips on how this might work?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Adding a parameterless constructor to `LocalizedBinding` and appending `Path=` to the binding fixes it.

Comment: You might look at how the excellent MvvmCross does it. https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross see: `MvxLanguageConverter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed by adding a parameterless constructor to the `LocalizedBinding` class

```cs
public class LocalizedBinding : Binding {
    public LocalizedBinding() {
        Source = Application.Current.Resources["LocalizedStrings"];
    }

    public LocalizedBinding(string path) : base(path) {
        Source = Application.Current.Resources["LocalizedStrings"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try and put a Localization class into your App.xaml, then on Application_Launching check which language the user has set. Everywhere that you display the text you then refer to the App.xaml class.